# How can Rpi4B python use USB Serial AT commands to control a 4G/LTE MiFi modem to text SMS?

Tags: pi-4, gsm, hat

I have purchased [this](https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-base-hat-3g-4g-lte-minipcie-cards/) 4G HAT and I'm using it with [this](https://sixfab.com/product/quectel-ec25-mini-pcle-4glte-module/) module in a raspberry 4. I use the USB connection.

I installed a ppp connection and everything is working correctly. My problem is: how do I send AT commands? I want to test several things, such as send sms or put the module in sleep mode.

I tried solutions like the ones shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161197/how-to-send-receive-sms-using-at-commands). However I don't know which device I should choose (in the example ttyACM0) and I tried a few but it gives the error:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB3: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyUSB3'
```

EDIT. The output for lusb:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2c7c:0125 Quectel Wireless Solutions Co., Ltd. EC25 LTE modem
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2a7a:9a18  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and dmesg (the section of correspondent to the GSM card)

```
[    3.212448] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    3.212527] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    3.234675] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[    3.239163] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[    3.239260] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[    3.239749] option 1-1.4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[    3.248897] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    3.250162] option 1-1.4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[    3.252576] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    3.253795] option 1-1.4:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[    3.255273] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[    3.257057] option 1-1.4:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[    3.257961] usb 1-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[    3.299767] qmi_wwan 1-1.4:1.4: cdc-wdm0: USB WDM device
[    3.300850] qmi_wwan 1-1.4:1.4 wwan0: register 'qmi_wwan' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.4, WWAN/QMI device, 5a:d7:9a:8e:3c:e9
[    3.309017] usbcore: registered new interface driver qmi_wwan
```

Comment: You question title is a bit to vague.  You 4G module can do a lot things, but I would suggest to narrow down to text SMS (what you specified), forget voice etc, and also focus on fastest LTE, forget slow guys like GMS etc. So if you agree, I can edit the title for you, to make it more specific, to something like this: "How can Rpi4B python use USB/UART/Serial AT commands to control a 4G/LTE module to text SMS?" You comments and counter suggestions welcome. Ah, lunch time, I need to go.  See you later.  Cheers.

Comment: When you plug your 4G Hat into the Pi using USB what shows up when you type ‘lsusb’ and ‘dmesg’? It should show you which port has been assigned.

Comment: @CoderMike, added the output for the commands. Meanwhile, I found that if running with sudo, I don't have that error. However, the script doesn't send any message. Just hangs and do nothing.

Comment: Thats weird, why do 4 usb ports get connected?

Comment: Ah, let me see. I would like to know how you connect Rpi to the SixFab module. Are you doing the ninja trick of barebone USB direct connect to barebone USB as shown in Appendix B of my penzu reading log? https://penzu.com/p/9fb61b9c.

Comment: The guide you followed is 10 years old, using Fedora8 Python 3000 (Ref 1). You might try the more up to date Ref (2). (1) How can Fedora8 Python3000 use AT commands send/receive Android phone SMS? - #RSK, StkOvlw 2010Jan29
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161197/how-to-send-receive-sms-using-at-commands

(2) SMS Gateway project using ZTE MF920V 4G MiFi modem - #Bilel, RpiStckExchng 2020jan31
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107923/sms-gateway-project-using-zte-4g-modem. (3) I have an ZTE MF920W+, so I can repeat you problem using Rpi4B python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same product. If you haven't yet found out it is /dev/ttyUSB2 port almost certainly based on your screen shot. Try apt install minicom. And start it with sudo minicom -s.  Go to 'serial port setup'. Change selection labeled A to /dev/ttyUSB2 and change selection F to no. Hit enter next, with 'Change ...' field blank and you back one menu. Save as 'dfl'. Their idea of 'default'. Then just select 'Exit' into program. Here most likely you won't see keyboard inputs because 'echo' is off on module. If you see ur keyboard inputs you can enter AT commands. The pdf of AT commands you can google. Osmocom website, some where in it, also has tech stuff about EC25. Mind the AT commands you enter b/c hard to know which command changed something you didn't want changed. Oh going back few sentences, if don't see ur keyboard inputs enable Microcom 'echo' by 'ctrl + a, then z to see menu,then e to enable echo and puts u back to blank screen that isn't at all helpful but playing around few times you'll get it. If you want to use adb look on github cat named 'ngohaibac' has repository bout '... ADB issues'. My experience wasn't exactly like his but googling error msg you'll figure it

Comment: Please structure the text into paragraphs, it is unreadable!

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/ttyUSB3` is likely busy because it is used by `pppd`. Run  `lsof /dev/ttyUSB3` to confirm.

If you need to send AT commands while using the PPP connection (typically, as a part of the startup sequence), you should add those commands to `pppd` configuration scripts (located in `/etc/ppp/chatscripts/` if memory serves).

If you want to test various AT commands interactively, you should stop `pppd`. You won't have the PPP connection, but `/dev/ttyUSB3` will not be busy and you'll be free to used it as you please.